# Permission denied when I try to run mpi example

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing

I get Permission denied when I try to run an mpi example.This is the code I am trying to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
  int rank, size;

  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);  /* starts MPI */
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);    /* get current process id */
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);    /* get number of processes */
  printf( "Hello world from process %d of %d\n", rank, size );
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

I complied it on the master VM, in a shared folder. I also generated ssh key and copied it to all slave VMs.I have a "hosts" file that has all the IP addresses of all VMs including the master vm.

I run the code with this command

`mpiexec -f hosts -n 4 hello_world

But I get

```
===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 2961 RUNNING AT 10.0.0.41
=   EXIT CODE: 255
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

By the way 10.0.0.41 is the Master VM.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried that before posting the question. This what I got sudo: mpiexec: command not found.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out.
I am using ubuntu, and it does not allow root access through ssh by default. So  I needed to allow root ssh access in all VMs and then generate an ssh key and copy it among every communicating VMs.

in more details, in case someone runs into the same issue.

I did  following steps in all VMs

## passwd root

then choose a passs word

## passwd -u root

## vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

edit "PermitRootLogin without-password" >>>> make it "PermitRootLogin yes"

## service ssh restart

Now you can generate an ssh key using ssh-keygen

and copy it with ssh-copy-id -i root@remote

do the same for every two communicating machines in your cluster.

Another thing I would like to mention is, I had a mistake in executing the mpi code.

I used ' mpiexec -f hosts -n 4 hello_world' I should have put ./ before the executable file. So the right command should be
' mpiexec -f hosts -n 4 ./hello_world'

Regards

Comment: This is just an easy way out. MPI is not supposed to run as root.